# Lagrangian for a forced system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

Suppose that for a non-forced system Lagrange's equations are
\begin{equation*}
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
m\ddot{x}+\left( k_{1}+k_{2}\right) x-k_{2}y+2c_{1}\dot{x}=0 \\
m\ddot{y}-k_{2}x+\left( k_{2}+k_{3}\right) y+2c_{2}\dot{y}=0.%
\end{array}%
\right.
\end{equation*}

But if the system is subject to external forces, say $F_{x},
$ $F_{y}$, which would be the Lagrangian in this case? Can we add $F_{x},$ $F_{y}$ in the right-hand sides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes: when the system is not conservative because of dissipation or driving, one must include generalized forces on the right hand side of the usual EL equation:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q_k}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial q_k}={\cal F}_k\, ,
\end{align}
where ${\cal F}_k$ is the generalized force on the (generalized) coordinate $k$.

You have already included damping so you need to include the driving term, again “by hand”.  In the simplest example of a harmonic force on a 1d system, the equations of motion would then be of the form
\begin{align}
\ddot{x}+\frac{\omega_0}{Q}\dot{x}+\omega_0^2 x = A\cos(\omega t)
\end{align}
where for a force $F_0\cos(\omega t)$ and $A=F_0/m$.